# R-squared as sample size increases

Tags: regression, variance, r-squared

How do I prove that $R^2=1-\frac{SSR/n}{SST/n}$ converges towards $\rho^2=1-\frac{\sigma^2_u}{\sigma^2_y}$ as $n \rightarrow\infty$,

where $\sigma^2_u=\operatorname{Var}(u)$ and $\sigma^2_y=\operatorname{Var}(y)$?

I have got the following:
$R^2=1-\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum{\hat{u^2_i}}}{\frac{1}{n}\sum{(y_i-\bar{y})^2}}$ and $\rho^2=1-\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum{(u_i-\bar{u})^2}}{\frac{1}{n}\sum{(y_i-\bar{y})^2}}$

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What are you struggling to prove, that $\dfrac{SSR/n}{SST/n}$ converges to $\dfrac{\sigma^2_u}{\sigma^2_y}$ or that $\rho^2 = 1 - \dfrac{\sigma^2_u}{\sigma^2_y}?$

Comment: Hi, it is the former that I'm trying to prove

Comment: What progress have you made so far? While this Stack does accept [tag:self-study] questions like homework problems, the way we handle them differs from how we handle other questions

Comment: Hint:  What are the definitions of SSR and SST?

Comment: I have edited the post above with what progress I have made

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution

Look at the section Moments of random ratios.

A key aspect is for  SST and SSR to be independent.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.